# Setting CheckBox value to checked

Tags: c#, checkbox

Some context, I'm still rather new at c# but I've been updating c# code that someone else wrote that is incomplete. I've come across this code that seems to be giving me an error.

```
gblnEnableSSL = Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt32(Utils.GetSetting("Program", "Configuration", "SSL", "0")));
```

`Utils.GetSetting("Program", "Configuration", "SSL", "0")` returns a string `"false"` currently.

I've found that removing `Convert.ToInt32()` solves my problem. But, I was unconvinced that someone simply added `Convert.ToInt32()` that broke the code. I checked in the repo and was surprised to find that the previous code of the same line use to be:

```
gblnEnableSSL = Utils.GetSetting("Program", "Configuration", "SSL", "0").ToUpper() == "TRUE";
```

Which seemed to work as well. The checkbox checked value is set by using `chkEnableSSL.Value = gblnEnableSSL;`

My question is whether or not there is a difference between setting the value using a bool value or a string value. Also, is a difference between `chkEnableSSL.value` vs `chkEnableSSL.Checked`?

**Edit:** I'm not getting a compiler or run-time error with the previous code. It does not perform the code afterwards. For example, i have `txtDataSource.Text = strDataSource;` immediately after and it does not set the text unless i comment out `gblnEnableSSL = ...` or remove the `Convert.ToInt32()`.

**Edit:**`Convert.ToInt32()` throws an exception but it did not break in VS because i didn't have "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" checked off.

Comment: "seems to be giving me an error" doesn't tell us what the error is, and we have no idea what `Utils` does. Between the two of those, it makes us very hard to help you...

Comment: @JonSkeet I edited the question to try to explain the error

Comment: It sounds like it's throwing an exception then - that's what `Convert.ToInt32` will do when presented with a value of `"false"`. If you can't see that exception, that suggests a bigger problem with your exception handling and general diagnostics.

Comment: @JonSkeet Regarding the exception handling, it appears i didn't have "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" checked when debugging in VS. It now breaks if i use `Convert.ToInt32`. Thanks!

Comment: Regardless of whether or not it breaks into the debugger, you should be able to see the exception somewhere - otherwise how are you going to spot problems in production? If you're just swallowing exceptions and not reporting them, you really need to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `GetSetting` is returning a string. The first code example you gave is converting this string to an integer and then converting it to a boolean. The only way this would work is if the string values stored for that key are either 0 or 1. On your second code block it looks as if the values being used were not string values of 0 or 1 but actual string values of true or false. If the values stored in your config file are still in the format of true or false then this would be why your first line is breaking. You can't convert false or true strings to an int. It does look like someone just added something to break the code.

Also you don't mention what technology you are using. You could be using winforms, wpf, webforms, or MVC. I'm going to assume this is a web technology you are using because checbox.value is something I usually see in javascript. General consensus in setting checkbox values in javascript is by using the .prop() property which takes in a string as the property you want to change and a value as the second parameter. E.G.

```
$( "input" ).prop( "checked", true );
```

http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Moral of the story is remove the conversion to the int32 and use `.prop()` to set that checkbox :)

Comment: Thanks for your help, it does seem like somewhere someone changed the value from 0 and 1 to "true" and false" (or just assumed that was the case). It's a windows forms application.